# Way to hide one users records from search results, but still have the records viewable by all?

Tags: permissions, search, global-search

We are batch importing a lot of data into multiple objects and once in SF we are going to de-dupe it.  I would like to have the data available to all to access but just leave it out of search results.

I am aware you can turn on 'limit search to items I own' but this is not going to work as our users frequently search on each others records.

Thanks.

Comment: Custom objects or standard ones?

Comment: @cricketlang - Accounts / Contact and a bunch of associated custom objects

Comment: Only strategy I could offer where would be to put that data into custom objects while you dedupe it and don't give them tabs so they aren't searchable. After deduping you could migrate the data from the custom objects over to the standard ones. Not really sure why you wouldn't dedupe before entry into the system but as far as an answer that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: @cricketlang - Thanks for your thoughts.  I completely agree that it would be best to dedupe prior to importing.  Unfortunately it is a 'live' a very fragmented data set We are porting a number of legacy systems into SF and the path of least resistance is to bring them in and the data in chunks.  Thanks for the idea of creating 'holding' objects but I think for my case this might end up making more work in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could use [Divisions](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getting_started_with_divisions.htm), but this feature is permanent and only meant for large data organizations (those with tens of millions of records or more). It's not likely that support would enable this feature to fix your problem, which sounds temporary.

In reality, the list of options you've already suggested are about your only choices: reduce security permissions so the users can no longer see those records, or instruct users to use "Limit search to items I own". There's no way to configure search to exclude certain records otherwise.